Use scipy.integrate.nquad to integrate integrals whose result is a complex number
I want to try to numerically integrate the intergal of 1/(1+x**2+y**2), where y is from 0 to sqrt(16-x**2) and x is from 0 to 5.
The problem is that the result is a complex number.
Can scipy.nquad handle it or are there any other functions?
With scipy.nquad the line flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b) gives the error, because it just can't compare complex numbers.

"gives the error": what error?

Can't compare complex numbers, when comparing complex numbers a and b.

scipy.integral.quad() has the argument complex_func=True. If set, it allows the function being integrated to return complex numbers. However, it has two problems: 1) It does not support multiple dimensions. 2) It does not support complex bounds, and your y bound is complex.

No, nquad can't do it as written, and there is not another function in SciPy that will. I think you need to transform the integral. Please check my math, but I think this is a valid approach. (LMK in the comments if there is something that needs to be fixed for posterity.)

So the first, entirely real part is:
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def f1(y, x):
    return 1 / (1 + x**2 + y**2)
pt1 = dblquad(f1, 0, 4, 0, lambda x: (16 - x**2)**.5)
pt1  # (2.2252005569348934, 8.0419480812278e-09)

and the second, imaginary part is something like:
def f2(v, u):
    return 1 / (1 + (u + 4)**2 - v**2)
pt2 = dblquad(f2, 0, 1, 0, lambda u: (8*u + u**2)**.5)
pt2  # (0.09653126045179834, 1.0412837259110574e-11)

Update: I think the math is correct. In Mathematica:
NIntegrate[1/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, Sqrt[16 - x^2]}]

produces the same result.

I'd be curious to know how such an integral arises, if your're willing to add that information to the question!
